# SQL Server combine rows with the same value into JSON Object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

If I were to group the rows, that would take a lot of work on the back end *and* the front end, and I'm hoping that by grouping results into a json object, it could be more efficient.
Here's a screenshot of my results:

[image]

Is it possible to have an output that looks something like this for each store number?
The only answers I've found involve converting the entire output to JSON.

```
"1000.0000": {
    "Insurance":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"800",
        "Monday Closed":"1700",
        "Tuesday Open":"800",
        "Tuesday Closed":"1700",
        "Wednesday Open":"800",
        "Wednesday Closed":"1700",
        "Thursday Open":"800",
        "Thursday Closed":"1700",
        "Friday Open":"800",
        "Friday Closed":"1700",
        "Saturday Open":"NULL",
        "Saturday Closed":"NULL"
    },
    "New Vehicle Sales":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"800",
        "Monday Closed":"1700",
        "Tuesday Open":"800",
        "Tuesday Closed":"1700",
        "Wednesday Open":"800",
        "Wednesday Closed":"1700",
        "Thursday Open":"800",
        "Thursday Closed":"1700",
        "Friday Open":"800",
        "Friday Closed":"1700",
        "Saturday Open":"NULL",
        "Saturday Closed":"NULL"
    },
    "Parts":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"700",
        "Monday Closed":"1900",
        "Tuesday Open":"700",
        "Tuesday Closed":"1900",
        "Wednesday Open":"700",
        "Wednesday Closed":"1900",
        "Thursday Open":"700",
        "Thursday Closed":"1900",
        "Friday Open":"700",
        "Friday Closed":"1900",
        "Saturday Open":"800",
        "Saturday Closed":"1500"
    },
    "Service":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"600",
        "Monday Closed":"2400",
        "Tuesday Open":"600",
        "Tuesday Closed":"2400",
        "Wednesday Open":"600",
        "Wednesday Closed":"2400",
        "Thursday Open":"600",
        "Thursday Closed":"2400",
        "Friday Open":"600",
        "Friday Closed":"2400",
        "Saturday Open":"700",
        "Saturday Closed":"1900"
    },
    "Used Vehicle Sales":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"800",
        "Monday Closed":"1700",
        "Tuesday Open":"800",
        "Tuesday Closed":"1700",
        "Wednesday Open":"800",
        "Wednesday Closed":"1700",
        "Thursday Open":"800",
        "Thursday Closed":"1700",
        "Friday Open":"800",
        "Friday Closed":"1700",
        "Saturday Open":"NULL",
        "Saturday Closed":"NULL"
    },
    "Leasing / Rental":{
        "Sunday Open":"NULL",
        "Sunday Closed":"NULL",
        "Monday Open":"700",
        "Monday Closed":"2000",
        "Tuesday Open":"700",
        "Tuesday Closed":"2000",
        "Wednesday Open":"700",
        "Wednesday Closed":"2000",
        "Thursday Open":"700",
        "Thursday Closed":"2000",
        "Friday Open":"700",
        "Friday Closed":"2000",
        "Saturday Open":"800",
        "Saturday Closed":"1700"
    }
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sat.[StoreNumber]
    ,Sat.[BranchName]
    ,Sat.[BranchDepartmentName] AS Department
    ,Sunday_Open   = Sun.[OpenTime]
    ,Sunday_Close  = Sun.[CloseTime]
    ,Monday_Open   = Mon.[OpenTime]
    ,Monday_Close  = Mon.[CloseTime]
    ,Tuesday_Open   = Tue.[OpenTime]
    ,Tuesday_Close  = Tue.[CloseTime]
    ,Wednesday_Open   = Wed.[OpenTime]
    ,Wednesday_Close  = Wed.[CloseTime]
    ,Thursday_Open   = Thr.[OpenTime]
    ,Thursday_Close  = Thr.[CloseTime]
    ,Friday_Open   = Fri.[OpenTime]
    ,Friday_Close  = Fri.[CloseTime]
    ,Saturday_Open   = Sat.[OpenTime]
    ,Saturday_Close  = Sat.[CloseTime] 

FROM [Stores] Sat
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Sun ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Sun.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Sun.[Department] AND Sun.[DayOfWeek] = 'Sunday'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Mon ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Mon.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Mon.[Department] AND Mon.[DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Tue ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Tue.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Tue.[Department] AND Tue.[DayOfWeek] = 'Tuesday'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Wed ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Wed.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Wed.[Department] AND Wed.[DayOfWeek] = 'Wednesday'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Thr ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Thr.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Thr.[Department] AND Thr.[DayOfWeek] = 'Thursday'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Stores] Fri ON Sat.[StoreNumber] = Fri.[StoreNumber]
        AND Sat.[Department] = Fri.[Department] AND Fri.[DayOfWeek] = 'Friday'
WHERE Sat.[DayOfWeek] = 'Saturday'
```

And here's some sample data

```
        CREATE TABLE Departments (
        Code_Store VARCHAR(255),
        Name_Store VARCHAR(255),
        Code_StoreDepartment VARCHAR(255),
        Name_StoreDepartment VARCHAR(255),
        Code_DayOfWeek VARCHAR(255),
        Name_DayOfWeek VARCHAR(255),
        OpenTime VARCHAR(255),
        CloseTime VARCHAR(255),
        Closed BIT(1)
    )
    INSERT INTO (
        Code_Store, 
        Name_Store, 
        Code_StoreDepartment, 
        Name_StoreDepartment, 
        Code_DayOfWeek, 
        Name_DayOfWeek, 
        OpenTime, 
        CloseTime, 
        Closed
    )

    VALUES 
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900001","Saturday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","600","2400",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","600","2400",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","600","2400",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","600","2400",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","600","2400",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900001","Saturday","800","1500",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","700","1900",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900001","Saturday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1001.0000","CarsCarsCars - Chicago","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","800","1400",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1900",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1900",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1900",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1900",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1900",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900001","Saturday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","700","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","700","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","700","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","700","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","700","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","800","1300",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900001","Saturday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900004","Monday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900005","Tuesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900006","Wednesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900007","Thursday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900008","Friday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1003.0000","CarsCarsCars - Sydney","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900001","Saturday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","700","0",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","700","0",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","700","0",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","700","0",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","700","0",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900001","Saturday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1004.0000","CarsCarsCars - Munich","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","800","1500",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","800","1500",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1005.0000","CarsCarsCars - San Diego","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","900","1400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","900","1400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900001","Saturday","800","1800",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_05","Collision Center","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900001","Saturday","800","1800",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900002","Sunday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","700","2400",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900001","Saturday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900004","Monday","700","2100",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900005","Tuesday","700","2100",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900006","Wednesday","700","2100",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900007","Thursday","700","2100",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_18","Leasing / Rental","900008","Friday","700","2100",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1006.0000","CarsCarsCars - Capetown","DEPT_IN","Insurance","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","900","1500",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_01","New Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900001","Saturday","900","1500",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900002","Sunday",NULL,NULL,"1"),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900004","Monday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900005","Tuesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900006","Wednesday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900007","Thursday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_02","Used Vehicle Sales","900008","Friday","800","1700",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900001","Saturday","800","1500",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900004","Monday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900005","Tuesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900006","Wednesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900007","Thursday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_04","Service","900008","Friday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900001","Saturday","800","1500",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900004","Monday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900005","Tuesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900006","Wednesday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900007","Thursday","700","2000",NULL),
        ("1007.0000","CarsCarsCars - Smallville","DEPT_06","Parts","900008","Friday","700","2000",NULL)
```

Comment: Firstly, any more than about 7 joins and the optimiser won't be able to give you the best possible plan. Secondly, you don't need all those joins, you can do this with a case statement. Can you give us some sample data and we can put something into JSON as an example?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov I have SQL Server Management Studio v. 18.4

Comment: And @JimJimson I'll do my best, I should also mention that I'm a UX designer and this is the first time I've used SQL *ever*, so please be patient if I don't give you exactly what you're asking for :)

Comment: @WushuDrew SQL Server Management Studio is a client tool, but I assume, that you have at least SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @Zhorov Figured it out
<br>
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @WushuDrew You need an approach based on string aggregation, for SQL Server 2016+ with `FOR XML PATH`, for SQL Server 2017+ with `STRING_AGG()`

Comment: I’ll @JimJimson, I couldn't get sqlfiddle to work, so I added some sample data to the post.

Comment: @Zhorov ok I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, let's start by saying that this is probably much easier done in the application layer as opposed to the database layer. And I'd fully advise you to do it there. Having said that, it is possible to get close to what you're after using [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) operators.

The below doesn't give you *exactly* what you're after, but it's close. And because of the way that extracting JSON from SQL Server works you need to hit this table 3 times in the same query, which is another reason you'd be better off doing this is in the application tier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code_Store, (
SELECT DISTINCT Code_StoreDepartment,
    (
    SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900001' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Saturday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900001' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Saturday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900002' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Sunday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900002' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Sunday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900004' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Monday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900004' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Monday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900005' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Tuesday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900005' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Tuesday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900006' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Wednesday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900006' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Wednesday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900006' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Thursday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900006' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Thursday Close',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900007' THEN ISNULL(OpenTime, 'NULL')   END) AS 'Friday Open',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code_DayOfWeek = '900008' THEN ISNULL(CloseTime, 'NULL')  END) AS 'Friday Close'
    FROM Departments OpenCloseTimes
    WHERE OpenCloseTimes.Code_Store = departments.Code_Store
    AND OpenCloseTimes.Code_StoreDepartment = departments.Code_StoreDepartment
    GROUP BY Code_Store, Code_StoreDepartment
    FOR JSON PATH
    ) OpenCloseTimes

FROM Departments departments
WHERE departments.Code_Store = stores.Code_Store
FOR JSON PATH
) [Departments]
FROM Departments stores
WHERE stores.Code_Store = '1001.0000'
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can generate the expected JSON using only `FOR JSON` statement, because you have variable keys, but one possible approach is to use `FOR JSON` and string aggregations. For SQL Server 2016 you need to use `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation:

Table (with correct and simplified data):

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
    Code_Store VARCHAR(255),
    Name_Store VARCHAR(255),
    Code_StoreDepartment VARCHAR(255),
    Name_StoreDepartment VARCHAR(255),
    Code_DayOfWeek VARCHAR(255),
    Name_DayOfWeek VARCHAR(255),
    OpenTime VARCHAR(255),
    CloseTime VARCHAR(255),
    Closed BIT
)   
INSERT INTO Departments (
    Code_Store, 
    Name_Store, 
    Code_StoreDepartment, 
    Name_StoreDepartment, 
    Code_DayOfWeek, 
    Name_DayOfWeek, 
    OpenTime, 
    CloseTime, 
    Closed
)   
VALUES 
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900001','Saturday',NULL,NULL,'1'),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900002','Sunday',NULL,NULL,'1'),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900004','Monday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900005','Tuesday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900006','Wednesday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900007','Thursday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900008','Friday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900001','Saturday',NULL,NULL,'1'),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900002','Sunday',NULL,NULL,'1'),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900004','Monday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900005','Tuesday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900006','Wednesday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900007','Thursday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1001.0000','CarsCarsCars - Chicago','DEPT_02','Used Vehicle Sales','900008','Friday','800','1700',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900001','Saturday','800','1400',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900002','Sunday',NULL,NULL,'1'),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900004','Monday','800','1900',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900005','Tuesday','800','1900',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900006','Wednesday','800','1900',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900007','Thursday','800','1900',NULL),
    ('1003.0000','CarsCarsCars - Sydney','DEPT_01','New Vehicle Sales','900008','Friday','800','1900',NULL)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH JsonForStoreAndDepartment (Code_Store, Json) AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT d.Code_Store, CONCAT('"', d.Name_StoreDepartment, '":', a.Json)
   FROM Departments d
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Sunday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Sunday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Sunday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Sunday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Monday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Monday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Monday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Monday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Tuesday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Tuesday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Wednesday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Wednesday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Wednesday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Wednesday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Thursday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Thursday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Thursday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Thursday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Friday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Friday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Friday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Friday Close],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Saturday' THEN OpenTime END) AS [Saturday Open],
         MAX(CASE WHEN Name_DayOfWeek = 'Saturday' THEN CloseTime END) AS [Saturday Close]
      FROM Departments 
      WHERE d.Code_Store = Code_Store AND d.Name_StoreDepartment = Name_StoreDepartment
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
   ) a (Json)
), JsonForStore (Code_Store, Json) AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT d.Code_Store, STUFF(a.Json, 1, 1, '')
   FROM JsonForStoreAndDepartment d
   CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT CONCAT(',', Json)
      FROM JsonForStoreAndDepartment
      WHERE Code_Store = d.Code_Store
      FOR XML PATH('')
   ) a(Json)
), JsonFinal (Json) AS (
   SELECT CONCAT(',"', Code_Store, '":{', Json, '}')
   FROM JsonForStore
   FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT CONCAT('{', STUFF(Json, 1, 1, ''), '}')
FROM JsonFinal
```

Result:

```
{
   "1001.0000":{
      "New Vehicle Sales":{
         "Sunday Open":null,
         "Sunday Close":null,
         "Monday Open":"800",
         "Monday Close":"1700",
         "Tuesday Open":"800",
         "Tuesday Close":"1700",
         "Wednesday Open":"800",
         "Wednesday Close":"1700",
         "Thursday Open":"800",
         "Thursday Close":"1700",
         "Friday Open":"800",
         "Friday Close":"1700",
         "Saturday Open":null,
         "Saturday Close":null
      },
      "Used Vehicle Sales":{
         "Sunday Open":null,
         "Sunday Close":null,
         "Monday Open":"800",
         "Monday Close":"1700",
         "Tuesday Open":"800",
         "Tuesday Close":"1700",
         "Wednesday Open":"800",
         "Wednesday Close":"1700",
         "Thursday Open":"800",
         "Thursday Close":"1700",
         "Friday Open":"800",
         "Friday Close":"1700",
         "Saturday Open":null,
         "Saturday Close":null
      }
   },
   "1003.0000":{
      "New Vehicle Sales":{
         "Sunday Open":null,
         "Sunday Close":null,
         "Monday Open":"800",
         "Monday Close":"1900",
         "Tuesday Open":"800",
         "Tuesday Close":"1900",
         "Wednesday Open":"800",
         "Wednesday Close":"1900",
         "Thursday Open":"800",
         "Thursday Close":"1900",
         "Friday Open":"800",
         "Friday Close":"1900",
         "Saturday Open":"800",
         "Saturday Close":"1400"
      }
   }
}
```